# Don't understand this SystemError about new style getargs when using PIL putpixel on a grayscale image

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm using Pyhon3.6, trying to generate an image using the Pillow Library (Updated) in the following way:

```
im = Image.new('L', (100, 100), grayscale_color)
for x,y,color in zip(cx.row, cx.col, cx.data):
    v = grayscale_color - color
    im.putpixel((x, y), v) # bugged instruction
```

But am getting a:

```
SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple error
```

Since the image is a grayscale image (`'L'` parameter in the Image creation), the `putpixel` function would expect a single value, not a tuple, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code looks OK to me and I cannot reproduce the error using Python 3.8.0 and pillow 6.2.1 (using my own made-up data). Please [edit] your question and provide a runnable [mre] of the problem.

Comment: I was able to duplicate the error by passing a float value as the last argument to `.putpixel()`.  If `grayscale_color` was a float, the error would have occurred on the `Image.new()` line, so it must be `color` (coming from `cx.data`) that's non-integral.

Comment: Thanks to @jasonharper, I have forced the input as int(v) in order to solve.